# How do I add further changes to a stash in Git

Tags: git, git-stash

Suppose that I have stashed some changes and I want to add further changes into the same stash (such as `stash@{0}`). Is there an easy way to do this? What about combining two stashes into a single one?

Comment: What's preventing you from just restoring the stash, modifying it, and stashing it again.  If you want to combine to stashes, just get both of them, and store it again.

Comment: @LeifAndersen: It's a pain when you have further changes that you don't want to add into the stash

Comment: Stash the changes you don't want in there first?

Comment: Isn't the difficulty that if you have (1) further changed a file that is modified in the stash, and (2) have not _staged_ your further change, then `git stash pop` will fail with the _unhelpful_ message "error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge: ... Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge" whereas "… Please add your changes to the index before popping" might give us a clue? (Although, you still have to reconcile your new change with your stashed change)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I don't see any "`git stash`" option allowing to modify an existing git stash.

A possible way to achieve this would be:

- stash your additional changes (`stash@{1}`)
- stash everything else (`stash@{2}`)
- create a `tmp` branch from the commit (`HEAD`) your are currently modifying
- `git stash pop` twice
- `git stash`, creating a new `stash@{1}` with both content in it,
- deleting your temporary branch and checkouting the initial branch you where in
- `git stash pop` once (to restore all the pending changes)
- continue your selective stash

---

Five years later, [Powerslave](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1763363/powerslave) proposes [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8060289/how-do-i-add-further-changes-to-a-stash-in-git/8060523?noredirect=1#comment67618855_8060523):

> The branching magic is completely unnecessary.
>   You could simply
>
> 1. Create a new stash with whatever you have.
> 2. `git stash apply` both changesets (you can `git stash pop` instead, but in that case you're in trouble if you accidentally screw up).
> 3. Create a new stash with these merged changes.
> 4. `git stash drop` the other two changesets if you used `apply` instead of `pop`

Comment: @Casebash: I agree. Time for writing a patch to add this feature, but I suspect the problem can quickly becomes quite complex to manage.

Comment: If you want some ideas, consider the TortoiseHg Workbench Shelve tool. Its workflow works really well for this kind of problem: Create shelves and add or remove stuff from them as you like from your working copy, or even between shelves.

Comment: That's overcomplicated, I believe. The branching magic is completely unnecessary. You could simply 1. Create a new stash with whatever you have. 2. `git stash apply` both changesets (you can `git stash pop` instead, but in that case you're in trouble if you accidentally screw up). 3. Create a new stash with these merged changes. 4. `git stash drop` the other two changesets if you used `apply` instead of `pop`

Comment: @Powerslave Nice. I guess I did not thought of that 5 years ago. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: @VonC Nevertheless thank you for your answer! I was interested if there is any convenient way around and you pointed out just what I wanted to know. Forgot to hit +1, sorry, I'll follow up now.

Comment: when i attempt this...i get "Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge - Aborting"

Comment: @TimBoland It is best to ask a new question with specific details, to see why you get that message.

Answer (score 24):

I don't think we have to follow all these steps,

git stash pop [this will apply your last stashed changes stash{@0}]
then again say, git stash [this will create new stash will all the changes to stash@{0}]

NB: it is only this simple if your further changes don't require a merge with your stashed changes. If they do, you can `git add .` before stash pop *or* follow the more careful process in one of the other answers.

Comment: I am not sure why someone has down-voted this answer, as it seems to be valid... at least in most of the cases :)

Comment: `Simple is better than complex.` https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/#id2

Comment: It's just not what op's question is. Supposed I have changed file A and file B and then stashed file A into stash 0. Then I continued working on file A such as it is now A'. I would then like to stash file B alongside the original file A. I don't want to unstash, effectively merging A into A'. It's a different set of operations. https://stackoverflow.com/a/8060523/7821547 has the right explanation for the mechanic OP is asking about.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot add new changes to an old stash, but you can combine and create a new stash that includes both your current changes and the old stash. Here's how you can do it:

1. Create the initial stash:

```git
git stash save -u "initial stash"
```

---

2. Make further changes that you want to add to the initial stash in your repository.

---

3. Stage all the changes:

```git
git add .
```

---

4. List all the stashes available in your repository:

```git
git stash list
```

You will see an output like this:
`stash@{0}: On main: initial stash`

---

5. Apply your initial stash on top of your additional changes:

```git
git stash apply stash@{0}
```

---

6. (Optional step) Resolve any conflicts that may arise between your initial stash and the current changes using your IDE.

---

7. Create a new stash that combines your initial stash changes and the recent changes:

```git
git stash save -u "initial stash combined with new changes"
```

---

8. Apply your combined stash:

```git
git stash apply stash@{0}
```

---

9. Delete your initial stash:

```git
git stash drop 1
```

You will see an output like this:
`Dropped refs/stash@{1}`

---

By following these steps, you can effectively combine your initial stash with new changes and continue your work.

Answer (score 1):

An old question, but I feel it still is missing the right answer: **[Do not use `git stash`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27117335/23118), use [temporary commits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75010635/23118) and/or temporary branches**.

> Suppose that I have stashed some changes and I want to add further changes into the same stash (such as stash@{0}). Is there an easy way to do this?

Yes, when you use normal, uncomplicated commits, this is just a normal interactive rebase with an `edit` action.

> What about combining two stashes into a single one?

When you use normal, uncomplicated commits, this is just a normal interactive rebase with a `fixup` action.