# automatically stash save/pop changes on git rebase?

Tags: git, git-stash

my git workflow uses rebase a lot. I always fetch upstream changes (the main repo i forked from) and then merge to my branches, and then rebase to remove useless (to me :D) merge commits and tree splits.

one thing on this workflow that annoys me is:

```
$ git rebase upstream/master
Cannot rebase: You have unstaged changes.
Please commit or stash them.

$ git stash
Saved working directory and index state WIP on cc: abc1234 Merge remote-tracking branch 'upstream/master' into local_branch
HEAD is now at abc1234 Merge remote-tracking branch 'upstream/master' into local_branch

$ git rebase upstream/master
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: awesome code change

$ git stash pop
```

so here we have 4 commands, 1=failed rebase, 2=stash, 3=rebase, 4=stash pop. anything but 3 is just mindless work.

So, the question is: What is the most recommended way of automating it? an alias to run git stash/rebase/pop everytime? some git config that forces rebase to stash or treat it as another commit to reapply afterwards? something else?

Comment: Why would you merge then rebase instead of just rebasing from the get-go ?

Comment: @AndrewC i mentioned it on the workflow just because most of the time merge will 'rebase' since i force ff-only... i can probably remove that as it is unimportant. on the example i left it out.

Comment: In the case I echo Torek's response.  Commit then rebase and cleanup after the fact as needed.

Comment: a very similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30208928/can-git-pull-automatically-stash-and-pop-pending-changes

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Edit: As of Git version 1.8.4, but with an important side bug fixed in Git version 2.0.1, `git rebase` now has `--autostash`.  You can configure `git rebase` to use `--autostash` by default as well, with `git config --global rebase.autoStash true`.  Please note the following sentence from [the documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rebase.html):

> However, use with care: the final stash
>    application after a successful rebase might result in non-trivial
>    conflicts.

(I still prefer to just make commits.)

#### TL;DR answer: just make a commit (then unmake it later)

It may help you to realize that `git stash` is really just `git commit` (in a more complicated form, which commits the index first, then the work-tree—when you apply a stash, you can maintain the separation of index and work-tree, or combine them into just a work-tree change).

What makes a stash special is that the commits it makes—the two or, with `-u` or `-a`, even three commits—are made in an unusual form (as a merge commit that's not really a merge) and not placed on any branch (instead, the special `refs/stash` reference is used to retain and find them).

Since they're not on a branch, `rebase` does not touch them, and in your workflow, it's the `git stash pop` that brings the work-tree changes into your new work-tree.  However, if you make your own (normal) commit, on a branch, and rebase and include that commit, this normal commit will be rebased along with any others.  We'll get to one last problem in a moment; for now, let's draw this up, as a series of commits that do (or don't) get rebased:

```
... do some work ...
... make some commits ...
... more work ...
... do something that causes upstream/master to update, such as git fetch upstream
$ git stash
```

At this point, here's what you have:

```
... - o - * - A - B - C     <-- HEAD=master
           \          |\
            \         i-w   <-- stash
             \
              @-@-@         <-- upstream/master
```

Here, `A`, `B`, and `C` are your commits (I'll assume you've made 3), all on branch `master`.  The `i-w` hanging off commit `C` is your stash, which is not on the branch, but is still a two-commit ["git stash bag"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20409853/1256452) and is actually attached to your latest commit (`C`).  The `@` commits (there might be just one) are the new upstream commits.

(If you have made *no* commits, your stash-bag hangs off commit `*`, and your current branch points to commit `*`, so that `git rebase` has no work to do other than move your current branch pointer forward.  Everything works out the same, in this case, but I'll assume there are some commits.)

Now you run `git rebase upstream/master`.  This copies your commits to new commits, with new IDs and new parent IDs, so that they sit atop the last `@`.  The stash-bag does not move, so the result looks like this:

```
... - o - * - A - B - C     [abandoned, except for the stash]
           \          |\
            \         i-w   <-- stash
             \
              @-@-@         <-- upstream/master
                   \
                    A'-B'-C'   <-- HEAD=master
```

You now use `git stash pop`, which restores the i/w stuff as work-tree changes, erasing the `stash` label (more precisely, popping it so that `stash@{1}`, if it exists, is now `stash`, and so on).  That releases the last references to the original `A - B - C` chain, and means we don't need the `i-w` bit either, which lets us redraw this as the much simpler:

```
... - @            <-- upstream/master
       \
        A'-B'-C'   <-- HEAD=master plus work tree changes
```

Now let's draw what happens if, instead of `git stash save`, you just do a `git commit -a` (or `git add` and `git commit` without -a) to create an actual commit `D`.  You start with:

```
... - o-*-A-B-C-D   <-- HEAD=master
         \
          @-@-@     <-- upstream/master
```

Now you `git rebase upstream/master`, which copies `A` through `D` to place them at the end of the last `@`, and you have this:

```
... - o-*-@-@-@     <-- upstream/master
               \
                A'-B'-C'-D'   <-- HEAD=master
```

The only problem is that you have this one unwanted extra commit `D` (well, `D'` now), instead of uncommitted work-tree changes.  But this is trivially undone with `git reset` to step back one commit.  We can use a `--mixed` reset—the default—to get the index (staging area) re-set too, so as to "un-add" all the files, or if you want them to stay `git add`-ed, a `--soft` reset.  (Neither affects the resulting commit graph, only the index state is different.)

```sh
git reset --mixed HEAD^   # or leave out `--mixed` since it's the default
```

Here's what that looks like:

```
... - o-*-@-@-@     <-- upstream/master
               \
                A'-B'-C'      <-- HEAD=master
                        \
                         D'   [abandoned]
```

You might think this is inefficient, but when you use `git stash` you're actually making at least *two* commits, which you then abandon later when you `git stash pop` them.  The real difference is that by making temporary, not-for-publication commits, you get those automatically rebased.

#### Don't be afraid of temporary commits

There's a general rule with git: make *lots* of temporary commits, to save your work as you go.  You can always rebase them away later.  That is, instead of this:

```
... - * - A - B - C   <-- mybranch
```

where `A`, `B`, and `C` are perfect and final commits atop commit `*` (from someone else or earlier published stuff), make this:

```
... - * - a1 - a2 - b1 - a3 - b2 - a4 - b3 - c1 - b4 - c2 - c3
```

where `a1` is an initial stab at `A`, `a2` fixes a bug in `a1`, `b1` is an initial attempt to make `b` work, `a3` is from realizing that `b1` requires `A` to be different after all, `b2` fixes a bug in `b1`, `a4` fixes a bug in `a3`'s change to `a2`, and `b3` is what `b1` should have done; then `c1` is an initial attempt at `C`, `b4` is another fix to `b1`, `c2` is a refinement, and so on.

Let's say that after `c3` you think it's mostly ready.  Now you run `git rebase -i origin/master` or whatever, shuffle the `pick` lines to get `a1` through `a4` into order, `b1` through `b4` into order, and `c1` through `c3` into order, and let the rebase run.  Then you fix any conflicts and make sure stuff is still right, then you run another `git rebase -i` to collapse all four `a` versions into `A`, and so on.

When you're all done, it *looks* like you created a perfect `A` the first time (or maybe with `a4` or some other one depending on which commits you keep and which ones you drop and whether you re-set any time stamps in things).  Other people may not want or need to see your intermediate work—though you can retain it, *not* combining commits, if that's useful.  Meanwhile you never need to have uncommitted stuff that you have to rebase, because you just have commits of partial stuff.

It does help to give these commits names, in the one-line commit text, that will guide your later rebase work:

```sh
git commit -m 'temp commit: work to enable frabulator, incomplete'
```

and so on.

Comment: This is a great answer. However what if while I am making my "dirty" commits as you say, I want to `git push` one of them and leave the rest. Is that possible?

Comment: The way to push one commit is to put it on its own branch (copy it, with `git cherry-pick`).  Assuming you have everything temp-committed, `git checkout -b pushme upstream/master` to create a named branch `pushme`, then `git cherry-pick <commit-identifier>` to copy it, then `git push upstream pushme:master` to push the one commit from local branch `pushme` to upstream `master`, for instance.  Once the push completes, you can rebase your temp chain onto the newly-updated `upstream/master` (and omit the one you copied, though rebase will do that automatically if it can).

Comment: @torek that is actually a perfect workflow when you rather the 'pick your commits to push'... i will definitely use that sometime. and surely point my friends that cry for `svn` to your comment! that is a very good workflow that i always dismissed a too complicated, but you are right, it is practical.

Answer (score 24):

**One Simple Answer:** `git rebase -i --autosquash --autostash <tree-ish>`

`-i = interactively rebase`

https://devdocs.io/git/git-rebase

---

This will...

- Auto stash your changes
- Interactively rebase from *`<tree-ish>`*

  - Auto position your squashes and fixups
- Auto pop stash in working directory after rebase

*`tree-ish`* can be a *commit hash* or a *branch name* or a *tag* or [**any identifier**](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html#_specifying_revisions).

Comment: `--autosquash` is usually not recommended. Branch history is important (unless you have careless teamates or you yourself do not know how to handle your commits, but that is a different problem, and kinda of paradoxical if you are rebasing interactively, it means you know how to tiddy up your commits already)

Answer (score 5):

The entire workflow in one command, including the fetching:

```
git pull --rebase --autostash [...]
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use an external tools called [git-up](https://github.com/aanand/git-up), which does exactly what you say for all branches. This will also help you keeping a clean history graph.

I've used for some years and it works pretty well, especially if you are not a git expert. If you add auto-rebasing feature you should know how to properly recover from failing rebase (continue, abort, ...)

### Install

Open a shell and run:

```
sudo gem install git-up
```

### Configuration

Open your global config file (`~/.gitconfig`), and add the following:

```
[git-up "fetch"]
    all = true    # up all branches at once, default false
    prune = true  # prune deleted remote branches, default false
[git-up "rebase"]
    # recreate merges while rebasing, default: unset
    arguments = --preserve-merges
    # uncomment the following to show changed commit on rebase
    # log-hook = "git --no-pager log --oneline --color --decorate $1..$2"
```

See the [official documentation](https://github.com/aanand/git-up#configuration) for more options.

### Invocation

If everything is configured well, just run:

```
git up
```

This is (roughly) equivalent of executing the following:

```
git stash
git fetch --all
[foreach branch]
    git rebase --preserve-merges <branch> <remote>/<branch>
    git merge --ff-only <branch>
[end foreach]
git checkout <prev_branch>
git stash pop
```

Comment: Git use tons of magic by itself, that's why the commands are split in porcelain and plumbing. `git-up` only does in a sequence of "safe" porcellain commands. If anything "bad" happens you just end up in a rebase conflict merge scenario: a simple `git rebase --abort` solve everything. As you gain confidence and control of git, you gradually find the script useless though.

Answer (score 1):

Answer from [tjsingleton blogg](http://tjsingleton.name/2010/12/cleaner-git-history-stash-rebase-pop/)

make a command alias of :

> git stash && git pull --rebase && git stash pop

**update**

If you are using idea, pushing with a dirty working dir, it will prompt a dialog, choose rebase / merge,  it will do stash, rebase / merge and pop automatically.