# How to PR only some commits?

Tags: git, github

There is a github project with default branch `product/master` owned by someone other.
I want to add some feature to this project. The problem is that before I start develop this feature, I need to *configure* project for my hardware **changing source code files** (`conf.h`, `advanced_conf.h`, ...). But I don't want those configuration changes be PRed to original repo.

What way I should go to develop on some branch with changes ahead original, and after development done, exclude few commits and their changes from history?

There is a way to "remember not to add" some files every commit, but I think there must be something more effective.

How to deal with it more correctly?

1. I create a fork repo `my` with same default branch `my/master`
2. I create branches `my/config` and `my/feature-dev` from `my/master`
3. I change some config files in `my/config` and commit
4. I create a PR from `my/config` into `my/feature-dev`
5. I develop a feature in `my/feature-dev` and commit many times.
6. **(?)** Now I need somehow to create `my/feature-release` which is based on `my/master`, but containing commits I made to `my/feature-dev` excluding commits made by PR `my/config`=>`my/feature-dev`
7. I create a PR of `my/feature-release` into `product/master`, PR is accepted, everyone is happy.

So questions are:

- Is there a correct way doing this?
- How to clone branch excluding some known commit ids?

Comment: `I need to configure project for my hardware changing source code files (conf.h, advanced_conf.h, ...). But I don't want those configuration changes be PRed to original repo.` This is exactly the use case for [temporary commits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75010635/23118). For your local use you can very well have a `config` branch but you do not need to expose it to anyone else or create a PR, just rebase `feature-dev` on top of `config` whenever you update `config`.

Comment: For point 6, if all your temporary commits are in your `config` branch, and `feature-dev` is rebased on top of that, then what you ask for is simply a rebase with the `--onto` argument. So when you want to create a PR run `git branch feature-release feature-dev; git rebase --onto master config feature-release; git push origin feature-release`.