# Is it possible to keep or drop a commit multiple times based on convenience?

Tags: git, rebase

My branching looks like this

```
M1 --- M2 --- M3 --- ............. --- M50 --- M51
               \
                \
                 B1 --- B2 --- B3 --- B4
```

Here M is master commits and
B is branch commits

The commit B2 contains changes where I check execution times, thread ids etc in various functions and src files etc. Hence, commit B2 should not be merged.

In my development work, after I add B3 I want to have B2 changes to test locally but when I push B3 or B4 and make a build I do not want B2 changes. Similarly, if others create a branch from my B3 or B4 commit, I donot want them to have B2 changes.

So B2 is a commit that I need to add, remove, add, remove multiple times. Is there an easy way to achieve this?

I thought of reordering the commits and keeping B2 at top followed by a soft reset. But since B3 and B4 etc are also in same src files, there are often merge conflicts when I do an interactive rebase.

Thanks in advance.

P.S: I have pushed B2, B3, B4 to remote as of now. Next I want to remove B2, add B5 (for a build), add B2 (test locally) and something similar for B6 and so on.

Comment: I keep things like that in a (private) branch that I can then apply/remove rather eaily: `git show X/my-hack | git apply` and then to remove: `git show X/my-hack | git apply -R`.... so, do not keep it as a commit in the _real_ branches.

Comment: What is the meaning of "check" here: "The commit B2 contains changes where I *check* execution times, thread ids etc in various functions and src files etc". Do you log it, or make decisions based on it, etc? Could this logic be shared with everyone and toggled with a config setting? (e.g . `if DEBUG...`)

Comment: Have you had any success in using temporary commits for your workflow?

Comment: @hlovdal No not really but I am now used to using stash save and pop. I still need to resolve merge conflicts but atleast the files without conflicts and temporary changes are easy to deal with. But be careful if you're using stash save and pop. I had messed up sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

I think that Stacked Git/StGit (command `stg`) is a good fit for this
workflow.

Stacked Git is a stack patch mananger which extends the Git
workflow. Basically it makes it easy to manipulate what commits are on
your “stack”, which is the last commits on your branch to whatever depth
you want. So say you have three patches[1] that you sometimes want to use
and sometimes not: if they are your most recent commits then you run:

```
stg uncommit -n 3
```

So that those three commits become *patches* that you can push and
pop. Right now they will be pushed on the stack, but you can pop them
using their names (based on their commit messages).

#### `stg repair`

Stacked Git is just an application that uses the Git repository. So keep
in mind that it can become confused if you run some git(1) command that
affects the stack. Say with your three-applied patch stack that you run
git-rebase(1) and squash them down to one commit: these are just Git
commits and so it won't stay out of their way. The next time you run
stg(1), it might be confused as to what happened to your stack since it
doesn't match its own recorded metadata.

Use `stg repair` to fix such problems/confusions. I can't recall running
into a case where Stacked Git got too confused to recover itself.

#### Repository

You might want to manually install this program from the [repository](https://github.com/stacked-git/stgit). The
reason for that is that it has recently been rewritten and your package
manager might be using an old version. I prefer the rewrite because the
commands feel “instant” now instead of taking perhaps more than a hundred
milliseconds. And that matters for this kind of CLI application.

#### Demo

```
cd /tmp
tmp=$(mktemp -d)
cd $tmp
git init
git commit --allow-empty -m1
# After the first commit
stg init
printf 'temporary, dev-only change\n' > dev-only.txt
git add dev-only.txt
git commit -mTEMP
# Now you can pop and push “TEMP” on the stck
stg uncommit
# Remove it
# (The name is based on the commit message)
stg pop
# Put it back
stg push
```

#### Notes

1. I use “commits” and “patches” kind of loosely, but it's better to think
   of these things as patches since that's how they are applied (pushed)
   and unapplied (popped)

Answer (score 0):

Reorder your branch to

```
B1 --- B3 --- B4 --- B2
```

so you have your [temporary B2 commit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75010635/23118) on top your otherwise normal commits.

Yes, you will probably get some conflicts from this<sup>1</sup>, but those will occur at some point in any case (e.g. when you want to remove B2 for delivery later).

---

Assuming your branch with the Bx commits is named `myfeature`, as a workflow you can create a `myfeature.testing` branch that points to B2 and let `myfeature` "only" point to B4 in the example above.

Then for later B5 and B6 commits you either

1. Create those commits on `myfeature` and then run `git rebase myfeature myfeature.testing`.

E.g. from

```
B1 --- B3 --- B4 --- B5 --- B6
                \           ^ myfeature
                 +-- B2
   myfeature.testing ^
```

to

```
B1 --- B3 --- B4 --- B5 --- B6 --- B2
                  myfeature ^      ^ myfeature.testing
```

2. Create those commits on `myfeature.testing` and then run `git rebase --interactive myfeature` to reorder B2 to be HEAD, then `git checkout myfeature; git merge --ff myfeature.testing^` to bring `myfeature` up to B6 (or whatever commit is latest, only excluding the B2 commit).

E.g. from

```
B1 --- B3 --- B4 --- B2  --- B5 --- B6
              ^ myfeature           ^ myfeature.testing
```

to

```
B1 --- B3 --- B4 --- B5 --- B6 --- B2
                  myfeature ^      ^ myfeature.testing
```

3. Same as 2) but not doing an interactive rebase before the end where you are ready to deliver your work and you just delete B2 in the rebase.

E.g. from

```
B1 --- B3 --- B4 --- B2  --- B5 --- B6
              ^ myfeature           ^ myfeature.testing
```

to

```
B1 --- B3 --- B4 --- B5 --- B6
              ^ myfeature   ^ myfeature.testing
```

and then `git checkout myfeature; git merge --ff myfeature.testing`

```
B1 --- B3 --- B4 --- B5 --- B6
                            ^ myfeature.testing
                            ^ myfeature
```

---

<sup>1</sup> I recommend [using KDiff3 to resolve those](https://github.com/hlovdal/git-resolve-conflict-using-kdiff3).