# Github: Ignore a specific file when merging upstream from a fork

Tags: git, github, vercel

I have a fork of a project that is in production - the project has a scheme.json file that is used to set the colors and basic themes of the website in question. I have made some bug fixes and whatnot on my fork to the rest of the project, and I want to merge these changes back into the original project WITHOUT overwriting their scheme.json file. How can I do this?

Note: The scheme.js file needs to be in the repositories (can't do gitignore) because Vercel is pulling from the repository to host the website.

Answer (score 1):

Not the cleanest approach but I think you can achieve this by creating a new branch from the original fork (without local changes), then pulling the latest changes from the upstream

```
git checkout <original forked commit>
git checkout -b <merge-branch>
git pull <upstream-remote> <upstream-branch>
```

and then merge your local change branch to that new merge branch without commit using `--no-commit` option so that you can exclude the intended file in the merge commit. Say if I want to ignore `scheme.json` file, I run the following commands

```
git merge --no-ff --no-commit <local-branch>
git reset HEAD scheme.json
git checkout -- scheme.json
git commit -m "Merge <local branch> to <merge branch>"
```

Afterwards, you can push the new branch to GitHub which you can then create a merge request from that new branch to the upstream branch

```
git push <forked remote> <merge-branch>
```

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](https://vercel.com/docs/), it looks like Vercel provides a way to set:

- [custom environment variables](https://vercel.com/docs/deployments/environments#environment-variables) when running your application
- the ability to [configure a build command](https://vercel.com/docs/deployments/configure-a-build#build-and-development-settings) when you deploy your application

The above features (any one of them actually) allows you to have a versioned file, and a runtime which differs between your development setup and the production setup :

- you can switch your scheme file from plain json to javascript, and have some values read from the environment :

  ```
  settings.color = process.env.MYAPP_COLOR || "purple"
  ```
- you can set an action in your `package.json` (e.g: `npm run deploy-prod` or `yarn run deploy-prod` ?) which copies or symlinks a `settings.prod.json` file, while using a `settings.dev.json` file in your development environment.

---

Other than that: one quick way to merge your current code is:

- create a commit where you restore the production values for your settings,
- merge that code into your main branch, and deploy that version to Vercel,
- create a new commit which restores the development values which you had on your branch

Restoring the content of a file (scheme.json in that example) from a specific commit is :

```
git checkout <commit sha or name> -- scheme.json
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to merge these changes back into the original project WITHOUT overwriting their scheme.json file. How can I do this?

This is a perfect example of what you should check in as a [temporary commit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75010635/23118). Then when cleaning up the branch with an interactive rebase before pushing the branch for a pull request it is trivial to trim down

```
pick 100106 bugfix 3
pick 100105 bugfix 2
pick 100104 ==== some other local changes to scheme.js ====
pick 100103 whatnot 2 that also modifies scheme.js
pick 100102 whatnot 1
pick 100101 bugfix 1
pick 100100 ==== my local colour theme changes in scheme.js ====
```

to

```
pick 100106 bugfix 3
pick 100105 bugfix 2
pick 100103 whatnot 2 that also modifies scheme.js
pick 100102 whatnot 1
pick 100101 bugfix 1
```

---

Notice that there is absolutely nothing Vercel specific in this. And there is nothing special with `scheme.js` either, it could be any other file instead or multiple files as well.

Maybe you could get a conflict when removing the temporary commits, and if so I recommend [using KDiff3 to resolve them](https://github.com/hlovdal/git-resolve-conflict-using-kdiff3).