# Python importing own git projects as packages - version conflicts

Tags: python, git, package, requirements.txt, toml

I am having problem with version conflicts in my python application. I have created my own python package with its own .toml file. Let us call it `my_package`. The .toml file includes other custom created packages made by me.

```
dependencies = [
        my-package1 @ git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/.../my_package1.git
        my-package2 @ git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/.../my_package2.git
]
```

Notice that the packages are given without a commit hash which points them to their lates version.

Now in my new python app I try to install the packages in my requirements file  but i get dependency conflicts. The requirements.txt file looks like below,

```
my-package @ git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/.../my_package.git@commit_hash
my-package1 @ git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/.../my_package1.git@commit_hash1
```

So the version specified in requirements.txt for `my-package1` is colliding with the version (latest) specified in my-package .toml file.

I know that this can be solved by for example deleting the commit_hash1 so the versions is the same but then we lose control of the different version. Can someone explain how this should be done.

Comment: I am not deeply familiar with the requirements handling for python, but from your description could you not just remove `commit_hash1` in a [temporary commit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75010635/23118)?

Comment: This was just what i wrote in my question... "I know that this can be solved by for example deleting the commit_hash1..."