# create a branch for each subfolder

Tags: git

I writing interactive tutorials where each tutorial lives in its own subdirectory of a git repo. Now the `main` branch will be published to my students. Previously, I did all my development work there and it contains a lot of unfinished tutorials, but I only want to publish finished and reviewed tutorials. So I created a backup branch `main_backup` and then deleted all unfinished, non production-ready stuff in `main`.

Now I have adopted a `develop` branch based off the empty `main` branch, which I can merge with `main` periodically. My aim is to have a `feature/tutorial` branch for each individual tutorial, so I can merge tutorials one tutorial at a time into `develop`. Then I want to be able to "batch"-publish several finished tutorials at once by merging `develop` into `main`. So far, this is the plan.

The problem arises when merging a single tutorial into `develop`. Here is how I create a `tutorial_1` branch (example for a feature branch):

- create new branch starting from `main_backup` (the last point where my work is stored).
- delete all tutorials that are not part of the `tutorial_1` branch (everything except tutorial 1)
- commit changes to tutorial 1 until it is finished.

When I try to merge with `develop` now, conflicts arise, because all tutorials are deleted there, but I am committing some altered files to a tutorial that is considered deleted by `develop` and alive by `tutorial_1`.

So, maybe i have gotten things wrong. My question is, what are the options that I have to achieve my goals of:

- individually reviewable, merge-able feature branches
- a `main` that is empty except for publishable stuff
- a `develop` that collects finished and reviewed features until the next release

Here is one solution I have worked out myself:

just create the feature branches based off `develop` and not `main_backup`, and then copy paste the tutorial folder for `tutorial_1` for example, and commit it. This has the benefit of being able to automerge into `develop`. Somehow this seems too hacky to me, to be the right solution.

Please help me, what is the right tool for my situation?

In my feature branch, I tried deleting all the unpublishable stuff, except the specific feature to be developed.

I was disappointed, because I expected an automatic merge would be possible. But it was not. I had to manually `git add` all the files I was working on in the feature branch and that were deleted in `develop`.

Comment: It's probably that git is not a perfect fit for your requirements, but you might consider using separate repos for each tutorial and use `git subtree` to copy them into the main repo when you are ready to publish.

Comment: `delete all tutorials that are not part of the tutorial_1` I suspect this is the main culprit of your problems. Important to have in mind: a merge commit signals to git that **every single change/contribution from all parents is forever completely consolidated going forward**. You are probably better of checking in that deletion as a [temporary commit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75010635/23118) which you then remove again before merging the final result.

Comment: OK, thank you for that link! That was the answer I was looking for, telling me that I did not understand how to properly apply git in this situation.

Comment: I can't tell if you know this already, but it looks like you're deleting files because you don't wish to commit them yet. But you don't have to commit every change you make. You can pick and choose which files to stage, and then commit just those. You can leave everything else alone if you wish.