# git solution to save codes for future use

Tags: javascript, git

I have added console.log to my projects to know what api are calling, how rabbitmq, elastic search and redis are working and showing step by step in the console. I can easily see where is the error.

What I want to do is I want to save the debugging codes (console.log) in git so that I can use in the future if needed.

Let's say, If I have error in the future when I change something in the code, I want to debug with my saved console. If everything is done, I want to save back my debugging code and commit only new changes to the remote repository.

How can I achieve this?

I tried with git stash but it is not exactly what I want. I cannot know what is code from debugging stash and what is my current changes.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Check in the debug logging changes as [temporary commits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75010635/23118). Assuming you are working on `my_feature_branch` you can create a branch `my_feature_branch.debug` that contains all your debug commits. Even after merging `my_feature_branch` into `main` there is no penalty to just let `my_feature_branch.debug`  be a "unconnected" branch that is lying dormant for potential future use (e.g. cherry-pick or rebase).