# Ignore changes to .gitignored files which were force-added

Tags: git

I want to add a certain file to my git repository, but ignore any subsequent changes.

In my .gitignore I have

```
path/to/ignored_files
```

And I had to

```
$> git add -f path/to/ignored_files/foo
```

to add these files.

(They were added in their correct initial state, but get overwritten as the application runs and I do not want those changes to be committed.)

Now these files show up in `git status` even though they are ignored.

Can I have them ignored going forwards, now that they exist and have changed?

Comment: Close to impossible. Either you ignore files and do not track them in the repository or you track them and then you track all changes. You can try [`git update-index --skip-worktree`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43535767/7976758) but that's unreliable inconvenient (everyone who clones your repo must run the command) temporary solution.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is [temporary commits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75010635/23118) to track those extra files in.

Answer (score 2):

You're asking how to ignore changes to tracked files, which [the Git FAQ says is not possible](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#ignore-tracked-files):

> Git doesn’t provide a way to do this. The reason is that if Git needs to overwrite this file, such as during a checkout, it doesn’t know whether the changes to the file are precious and should be kept, or whether they are irrelevant and can safely be destroyed. Therefore, it has to take the safe route and always preserve them.
>
> It’s tempting to try to use certain features of `git update-index`, namely the assume-unchanged and skip-worktree bits, but these don’t work properly for this purpose and shouldn’t be used this way.

The FAQ proposes an approach for config files, which would also work for this type of file as well:

> If your goal is to modify a configuration file, it can often be helpful to have a file checked into the repository which is a template or set of defaults which can then be copied alongside and modified as appropriate. This second, modified file is usually ignored to prevent accidentally committing it.

So if you keep the checked-in versions in another location and copy them into place with a script before running the first time, that should solve your problem.