# git thinks branch missing commits merged earlier

Tags: git, github, git-merge, git-squash

My team has recently transitioned to a GitHub Actions CI/CD workflow and we are encountering an issue that I'm uncertain how best to resolve.

First, I'll describe our current branching strategy:

We are a Salesforce stack shop that uses the [Org Development model](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/org-development-model). This means that each developer has their own sandbox, and in addition we have Integration, UAT, and Production environments.

We have created 3 long-lived branches in git that are meant to represent each of these non-developer sandboxes (`int`, `uat`, `main`). The intended workflow is as follows:

- All `feature` branches should be based from `main`.
- Once a `feature` branch is considered ready for QA, a Pull Request is opened to compare the branch to `int`. Once squashed and merged, a GitHub Action will deploy the delta to the Integration environment.
- Once QA is complete, a Pull Request is created to compare the `feature` branch to  `uat`. Once squashed and merged, a GitHub Action will deploy the delta to the UAT environment.
- After UAT sign-off, a Pull Request is created to compare the `feature` branch to `main`. Once squashed and merged, a GitHub Action will deploy the delta to the Production environment.
- If at any point `main` should be updated, the `feature` branch should be `rebased` on top of `main`.

The issue we have encountered is that after a `feature` branch has been merged into both `int` and `main`, our `int` branch still seems to think that it is behind the `main` branch. Example:

- `feature/A` with `commit1` has been squashed and merged into `int`, `uat` and `main` via Pull Requests and subsequently deployed to their relevant environments.
- `feature/B` is then created based on `main`, which includes the changes from `feature/A`.
- `feature/B` is ready to be merged into `int`, and a Pull Request is created.
- At this point, git does not see that `commit1` is already represented in `int` and wants to re-merge this commit into `int`.

Looking into it, I can see that `commit1` has a different hash in the `int` branch than the one in `main`. So, I believe I understand why git does not see these as the same commit, but I'm unsure what has caused the hash to change.

I'm certain I'm overlooking something here, or perhaps misunderstanding what is happening with git behind the scenes. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I’ve added a link. Hope it’s correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Once squashed ...

Stop doing that.

In the same way that adding comments as a deodorant to cover up stinking code is a bad idea, squashing branches because the version history stinks is also a bad idea (and that is always the reasoning behind why people want to squash branches on pull requests, although expressed as an euphemism like "clean up the branch" or whatever).

Using `fixup` or `squash` in interactive rebase *while working on a feature* is not only perfectly fine ([I am in no way advocating that commits are immutable and should never be changed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75010635/23118)), but more than that - almost required. However at the point *when creating a pull request* the history should be clean and proper (including [all commits pass tests](https://github.com/mhagger/git-test)) and squashing is wrong.

Squashing will ruin your ability to drill down problems with [`git bisect`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect). And as you have experienced it also breaks your workflow.