# How can I avoid fixing other peoples merges when doing a git rebase

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-rerere

I'm working a huge feature that can't be released in parts so I'm working on a feature branch. Every few weeks or so I try and do a rebase to keep myself up to date with dev.

The bit of code I'm working is nicely separated from the rest of the code so why do I end up having to re-fix merges that have already been made on the branch I'm rebasing from?

What's likely happening? What do we change to stop it happening?

Comment: See `man git rerere`

Comment: sounds to me that you need Automated testing and CI in your project

Comment: What mitigates the problem is to squash commits in your branch [interactive rebase your branch to squash your commits](https://garrytrinder.github.io/2020/03/squashing-commits-using-interactive-rebase). This assumes everybody does this and doesn't merge with the main branch, they rebase with the main branch. Changes on the same line still have to be resolved manually, of course.

Comment: @PeterPointer Using squash or not is a workflow decision and not relevant to the question.

Comment: You should absolutely not be squashing commits like suggested here. Squashing commits while working on some feature stuff [can be fine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78113599/23118), but doing that to adapt to other peoples changes is horribly wrong. What I guess you are looking for is some tool to make your rebase experience less painful, and I think using [`git imerge`](https://github.com/mhagger/git-imerge) will be such a tool since it will trigger whatever conflicts there will be in as minimal instances as possible.