# squashing multiple commits to a branch with conflicts

Tags: git

suppose I am working on a branch A from feature branch F, someone else from my team has created a branch B.
I and my teammate are doing commits in same file but in separate branches A and B respectively.
His PR is approved and I get Merge conflict on my branch.
I resolved conflict but there are 5-6 commits on my branch, my teammate will also have 2-3 commits on his branch.
Now can I merge my commits to one commit?

```
-------------F-------------
\                 \
A----              B-----
commit 1            commit 1
commit 2            commit 2
commit 3            commit 3
commit 4            Merge
resolve conflict 
commit 5
```

now can I squash commit 1 to commit 4 into one commit
something like

```
-------------F-------------
\                 \
A                  B(Merged)
squashed commit
```

I tried looking for same but couldn't find exact answer.

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to squash your pull request? [it is a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78113599/23118) that also makes rebase conflicts much more likely and also more severe when they occur. Rebasing with smaller commits gives a much better experience by reducing the risk of conflicts and when they occur they will be simpler to resolve (for an even more gradual approach in rebasing in tiny steps there is [`git imerge`](https://github.com/mhagger/git-imerge)). If you rebase non-squashed branch A on top of B you might get conflicts in commits 1-4 but then just copy solution from commit 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr:** scroll down to the last section on squashing commits

**Long:**

When you have conflicts, the 2 normal ways to resolve them are via merge or rebase. Let's assume your remote is called `origin`.

Resolve conflicts with merge:

```
git fetch
git switch branch-A
git merge origin/branch-F
# resolve the conflicts, stage and commit
git push
```

With a merge, you will add one merge commit to your branch which resolves the conflicts, and when you push your PR will be updated without any conflicts.

Resolve conflicts with rebase:

```
git fetch
git switch branch-A
git rebase origin/branch-F
# resolve the conflicts, stage them, and
git rebase --continue
# repeat resolving conflicts for all commits that have them, stage and continue
# once finished:
git push --force-with-lease
```

With a rebase you aren't adding new commits, but you are rewriting your commits to resolve the conflicts, so you mush force push your branch to update the PR.

Note with merge, there is only one place you can have conflicts, but with rebase, it's possible to have conflicts on multiple commits. If this is your case and you don't wish to deal with resolving conflicts multiple times, you could first squash your commits to a fewer number, and then do the rebase. (Or, as suggested in your question, if you would rather squash your commits anyway.)

**If you wish to squash your commits**, I recommend doing this first because it's not possible to have conflicts when squashing commits as long as you maintain the same order. There are multiple ways to squash commits, here's one:

```
git switch branch-A
git rebase -i --keep-base origin/branch-F
# now pick the top commit, squash the rest, save and exit the editore
# When the rebase finishes it will prompt you to write a combined commit message.
# now you have 1 commit on your branch instead of multiple
# now repeat the steps above for rebasing to resolve merge conflicts
```

Note that the options to rebase:

- `-i`: Interactive rebase. This enables you to control the rebase TODO list.
- `--keep-base`: Instead of rebasing onto `origin/branch-F` it will keep the base you started from so you don't have to deal with the conflicts yet.

Comment: Until rebase it looks good, what should I do after rebase completes. 
git status does not show any change in my branch.

Comment: @AnandMadhab if your branch has an upstream set (like `origin/branch-A`, then `git status` would probably show some commits ahead and some commits behind. Then you need to force push to update your branch. If you don't have an upstream, you may need to `git push --force-with-lease origin branch-A`.

Comment: Worked, thanks a lot. I struggled full day for this.