# How to convert GitHub squash and merge commits to merge commits?

Tags: git, github, git-merge, pull-request, git-squash

I have a personal project GitHub repository that used the **squash and merge** option for pull requests.

How do I rewrite the Git history so that the pull requests used the **merge commit** option instead of **squash and merge**?

Answer (score 3):

**Squash merges are destructive operations and there is no way to reverse them.**

It is a really, really bad practice and [you should stop using them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78113599/23118).

---

If you are lucky you might find traces of the original branch that was used to create the pull request, so that you could resurrect those commits and create a new branch on the last commit. With that you might change your main branch by discarding the squash commits and replace with real merges using reset, rebase and/or interactive rebase.

To hunt locally in your repository you can use `git reflog` or `gitk --reflog` to find "unconnected" commits that has not been discarded yet.

On the remote side I think github has some history references to commits in the pull requests that you might be able fetch.

This task will not be trivial but it will be a great learning experience for you. NB, start by making a copy of the whole repository directory so you have a backup to fall back to or to start over again.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by doing `git reset --hard` to before my first PR merge.

Then, I cherry-picked the individual commits of each PR and did `git push`.

This solution doesn't exactly use merge commits like GitHub, but I found out I actually like a linear history more.