# Show more source control related panels in vscode

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

In the source control panel in vscode I only see two or three panes of info but I watched a tutorial and the presenter had maybe 8 panels with much more information. How do I show these panels?

[image]

Comment: This is a kind of related post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74111434/how-do-i-restore-the-stashes-menu-in-visual-studio-codes-source-control-panel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you described is apart of an extension called [Gitlens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.gitlens).  It adds additional functionality (i.e. these panes you mentioned, among other things) to Visual Studio Code for working with Git.

The GitLens extension is apart of the Git Extension Pack extension, which contains a few other extensions as well (including Git History).

From the vscode [website](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/sourcecontrol/overview#_timeline-view):

[image]