# Extracting file from previous tagged version

Tags: git

I want to extract a file from the **last tagged version**:

- if the current head is at a tagged version, then take the previous one
- else, take the last tagged version.

I am doing something like that :

```
#!/bin/bash    
newtag=`git name-rev --tags --name-only $(git rev-parse HEAD) | sed 's|\([^\^]*\)\(\^0\)$|\1|g'`
if [[ "$newtag" == undefined ]];then
    # then the current version has no tag
    newtag=`git describe`
    oldtag=`git tag --list | sort -V | tail -n1`
else
    oldtag=`git tag --list | sort -V | tail -n2 | head -n1`
fi
# Now go grab the previous file : 
git stash
git checkout $oldtag --recurse-submodules
file=`latexpand paper.tex`
git checkout $newtag --recurse-submodules
echo "$file" > oldpaper.tex
git stash pop
```

is there a way to do that more cleanly ? I am sure what i did to find out the right tag to go to is sub-optimal...

Moreover, getting the file is somewhat clunky right now too. The problem is that i need to ran `latexexpand paper.tex` to get the file from the old verison of the repo, it is not already there. Thus, i need to checkout the older version (and stash what i currently have to do so). Is'nt there a way to ask git to run a command in the state of the `oldtag` version and give me back the output more cleanly ?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to do that more cleanly?

This sounds like a situation where you preferably could add an additional [worktree](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/git-worktree/info) where you just run `latexpand paper.tex`, and then have the script fetch the head of the other worktree (e.g. `git worktree list | awk '/the_other_worktree/{ print $2 }'`) instead of `git rev-parse HEAD`.

That way you can have modified files in the main worktree without it affecting the second one.

Bonus: you could then set it up as a [test](https://github.com/mhagger/git-test) and have it [run automatically](https://github.com/hlovdal/git-test/blob/readme/run-continously.sh) on every commit on a branch.

---

PS You should seriously try to [stop using stash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27117335/23118) and instead use [temporary, *normal* commits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75010635/23118) and/or temporary branches.

Comment: I'm already having this stuff run automatically through GitHub action to compile my latex and the corresponding latexdiff. since worktree allows to get a branch, I am not sure this is what I need as I need to get a tag, not a branch. But thanks for the links I learned something !