# How to git stash only the conflicting files in a git pull?

Tags: git, git-stash

I'm looking for a command(s) to `git stash` only the list of files that would be overwritten/conflicting when doing a `git pull`, all at once. I just want to accept all the remote changes and deal with all conflicts by stashing local.

I've only been discarding local changes that conflict or stashing all changes (I want to keep those that don't conflict), which isn't ideal.

Comment: You couldn't partially stash. Stash results in clean working directory.
You could `stash`, `pull`, `stash pop` and resolve your conflicts (in you case by resetting conflicting files, I suppose)

Comment: @markalex One can [`git stash push`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash#Documentation/git-stash.txt-push-p--patch-S--staged-k--no-keep-index-u--include-untracked-a--all-q--quiet-m--messageltmessagegt--pathspec-from-fileltfilegt--pathspec-file-nul--ltpathspecgt82308203) a list of files. I.e., it's possible  to stash partially.

Comment: @phd, sorry, was wrong. Then I guess it might be even possible to do what OP asked.

Comment: Hey, wouldn't `git pull -X theirs` be sufficient for this case? Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10697463/resolve-git-merge-conflicts-in-favor-of-their-changes-during-a-pull)

Comment: @markalex "*I guess it might be even possible to do what OP asked.*" I doubt it. It seems to be impossible to know in advance which files will conflict during `git pull`.

Comment: @phd, right. For some reason i thought about using `diff` after `fetch` in some clever way, but I completely forgot, that we are talking about working copy, and not committed changes.

Comment: @markalex Well, I think `git fetch` + a lot of scripting could help. But I'm certainly not gonna try. :-)

Comment: @phd I think we discussed it from purely theoretical standpoint, you know - for science. On practice, I believe, `git pull -X theirs` should do what author wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**Stop using git stash**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27117335/23118) and instead use [temporary commits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75010635/23118).

By doing that there is nothing special handling, just straight forward, normal git commands:

```bash
git commit -am "==== before pull ===="    # Temporary commit
git pull --rebase
git reset HEAD^                           # Undo temporary commit
```

In case of conflicts, [use KDiff3](https://github.com/hlovdal/git-resolve-conflict-using-kdiff3) to resolve them.

---

The above is as simple as it gets. Alternatively if you want a bit more control (say `pull` brings in a lot of changes and you only want to deal with some of it at the beginning) you could work with two branches, `somebranch` (which is tracking `origin/somebranch`) and `somebranch.mywork` which is the unpublished work you are doing.

Then you let `somebranch` strictly follow `origin/somebranch` and then rebase `somebranch.mywork` on top of that. When you eventually want to push changes from `somebranch.mywork` you simply (fast-forward) merge those changes into `somebranch` and push.