# Git: Do you have to do a commit after a pull from remote?

Tags: git, git-pull, git-remote

If I'm on a local branch and pull from remote, and then try to switch to a different branch, it tells me to commit or stash changes first. I figured that when I do the pull, I'd be getting all the new commits from the remote branch, and that my local branch would just be up-to-date with the remote. If I do an additional commit after this pull, the only new information I'd be adding is that I did the pull. Can I just pull without having to add a commit message after?

Comment: Either you had changes _before_ the pull or you had a merge conflict which you need to resolve.

Comment: You're right, I did have a local change I didn't notice. Thanks.

Comment: Do not include a "solution" in the question. The place for a solution is the Answer field. Accept an answer, your own or someone else's, to indicate your solution.

Answer (score 0):

> Git does NOT prompt you to commit/stash immediately after pulling from remote.

For this reason, I prefer setting a `stash` + `pull --rebase` by default ([Git 2.6+](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30209750/6309))

```bash
git config --global pull.rebase true
git config --global rebase.autoStash true
```

That way, a simple `git pull` will replay (rebase) my local commits (the one not yet pushed) on top of the refreshed `origin/myCurrentBranch`, making sure my local work is not overridden.

Any work in progress is automatically stashed first, then restored after the rebase.

Additionally, if I have "unsubmitted" work (local modification not yet added to the index and committed), the "autostash" part make sure the work in progress is saved before the pull, and re-applied after the pull.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly [prefer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75714620/23118) to do what VonC suggested more explicit and without any specific configuration:

```bash
git commit -am "==== before pull ===="    # Temporary commit
git pull --rebase
git reset HEAD^                           # Undo temporary commit
```

In case of conflicts, [use KDiff3](https://github.com/hlovdal/git-resolve-conflict-using-kdiff3) to resolve them.