# Git: How to checkout previous commit without committing changes?

Tags: git, git-checkout, git-stash

I want to checkout a previous commit, but I've made changes, so it's prompting me to commit or stash the changes first. I don't have the changes at the point where I want to commit them yet. Is this what `git stash` would work for? Would it save my changes such that if I checkout the previous commit and then return to HEAD, finish my changes and *then* commit, all my changes from before and after stashing would be included in that commit?

Comment: Note you can also make a wip commit and then amend it later.

Comment: Yes, you can use `git stash`. And if your changes include untracked files, see [How do you stash an untracked file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835501/how-do-you-stash-an-untracked-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, that's exactly what `git stash` is for. It will save your changes, and you will be able to restore them later with `git stash pop`. (That's the simple usage. `git stash pop` will get the last thing you saved.)

Say you were working on `main`.

```bash
git stash             # Saves and removes your changes
git checkout HEAD^    # Checkout previous commit
# Play around here.
git checkout main     # Go back to the branch you were using.
git stash pop         # Restore your work.
```

Comment: Expanding a little bit, you can have several different things in `git stash`, so `git stash list` will show you roughly what each is.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't have the changes at the point where I want to commit them yet.

Yes you do! You **do** want to create a commit, it's just that the commit will not be in its final form so it needs to be modified later, **and that's fine - that's basically the core functionality of using git!**

*If you consider commits and branches as immutable objects you are missing out on the vast majority of git's benefits.*

While git stash exists, you are much, much better of [never using it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27117335/23118) and instead just create normal, [temporary commits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75010635/23118) (with a naming convention that makes them visible as such<sup>1</sup>).

---

<sup>1</sup> And it does not only have to be `====` pre-/post-fix as suggested, I have a `ci` alias for `commit` and usually run `git ci -am ci` to do what `git stash` sort of would accomplish but without the benefits of creating a real commit. Because "ci" is clearly never a valid commit message on anything final it does not run the risk of being left in on the final branch pushed.