# Git stash. synchronizing the cache with another computer

Tags: git, github

How can a Git version control system (based on the `git stash` command) do:

1. saving changes to the cache
2. synchronize the cache through the repository with another computer
3. modify the changes on another computer and make a commit there already?

I failed to implement

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to implement this with stash instead of real commits?

Comment: @Андрей, use a temporary branch. At the local repo: commit, push, reset soft to update the local index, delete the branch. At the remote: restore cache from the pushed branch, remove the branch.

Comment: The stash is not a cache system. And commits are not set in stone. Just commit and push, fetch from the other side, and reset the temp commit there.

Comment: Do yourself a favour and [stop using stash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27117335/23118) and instead use [temporary commits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75010635/23118). None of the (many) shortcomings of stash applies to the scenario you describe when you use normal commits.

Answer (score 3):

The stash entries are also commits. You can create a ref on the head of a stash entry and then publish it.

```
# Create a stash entry with a meaningful message
git stash push -m "some description"

# Create a branch or a tag or any ref on the newly created stash entry
git branch stash_0 stash@{0}

# Push the branch "stash_0" to the remote
git push origin stash_0

# Pull the branch "stash_0" and apply the stash entry
git fetch origin stash_0
git stash apply FETCH_HEAD
```

If you insist on stashes, you can define a custom ref for such stash entries, so that they won't be confusing with regular branches and tags.

```
git push origin stash@{2}:refs/stashes/001
git push origin stash@{0}:refs/stashes/002

git fetch origin refs/stashes/001 && git stash apply FETCH_HEAD
git fetch origin refs/stashes/002 && git stash apply FETCH_HEAD
```

Comment: @Андрей : to illustrate that "stash entries are also commits": check `git log --oneline --graph stash`, `git log --oneline --graph stash@{1}` ...